# simple_html_dom find HTML inside script

Tags: find, simple-html-dom

Background: We use handlebars templates. Small ones, which are needed only once, we inserted inside script, inside HTML. HTML are pre-translated, once on release.

**Problem:**

With simple_html_dom we find all relevant texts. 
Except those who are in the script tag!

Example "normal"

```
 <h5 class="ues mt-1">Anmerkung ändern {bezeichnung}</h5>
```

Example inside script

```
 <script id="template-Liste-Anmerkungen" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
     <h5 class="ues mt-1">Anmerkung ändern {bezeichnung}</h5>
 </script>
```

We find all relevant texts per class *ues*:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();   
$html->load($strHTML, true, false);
$HTMLElemente = $html->find('.ues');
```

All *ues* are found, no matter how deeply they are interlaced inside forms and modals. But the *ues* within the script tag are not found. It's always pure, clean HTML, what can we do?

---

Yes, I have found similar questions, some were not sufficiently documented, none had a relevant solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to iterate through the script tags and load the contents separately.

```
$str = <<<EOF
 <script id="template-Liste-Anmerkungen" type="text/x-handlebars-template"> 
     <h5 class="ues mt-1">Anmerkung ändern {bezeichnung}</h5>
 </script>
EOF;

$doc = str_get_html($str);
foreach($doc->find('script') as $script){
  $sub_doc = str_get_html($script->innertext);
  foreach($sub_doc->find('.ues') as $el){
    echo $el;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Like in your answer, I load the string inside script in a new simple_html_dom();   
It works! Great!